# Empty value of select box doesnot give error (material design)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<md-input-container flex-gt-xs>
    <label translate>rule.type.title</label>
    <md-select name="type" ng-required="true" ng-model="vm.model.type"
               ng-change="vm.onRuleTypeChange(vm.model.type)">
            <md-option ng-repeat="(key,value) in vm.types" ng-value="key">
            <span translate>{{value}}</span>
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
    <div ng-messages="form.type.$error">
        <div ng-message-exp="['required']">
            <span translate>rule.type.errors.required</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container flex-gt-xs ng-if="vm.isRealTime(vm.model.type)">
    <label translate>rule.result.title</label>
    <md-select name="result" ng-required="true" ng-model="vm.model.result"
               ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}">
        <md-option ng-repeat="result in vm.results" ng-value="result">
            <span>{{result.name}}</span>
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
    <div ng-messages="form.result.$error">
        <div ng-message-exp="['required']">
            <span translate>rule.result.errors.required</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```

this is html of the page i am asking about.First container is for text input, second is for selectbox.

when i click save, only input places give errors, not comboboxes

[image: when i click save, only input places give errors, not comboboxes]

but when i click that boxx and leave the box without selecting anything, it gives error

[image: but when i click that boxx and leave the box without selecting anything, it gives error]

Why is that?

it is probbly because

```
  md-maxlength="50"
               ng-minlength="2"
```

inpt text has that rule so it cant have empty value. But what about selectbox?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7067 here they say

Comment: you should have at least one item as selected in select box conditionally

Comment: yes i know and want to have errors if no item was selected

Comment: md-select now works just fine.
Issue Fixed in version 1.13   https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8529

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked

```
<md-input-container flex-gt-xs>
            <label translate>rule.type.title</label>
            <md-select name="type" ng-required="true" ng-model="vm.model.type"
                       ng-change="vm.onRuleTypeChange(vm.model.type)">
                    <md-option ng-repeat="(key,value) in vm.types" ng-value="key">
                    <span translate>{{value}}</span>
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
            <div ng-messages="form.type.$error" ng-show="form.$submitted || form.type.$touched ||  form.type.$dirty ">
                <div ng-message-exp="['required']" ng-hide="form.type.$valid">
                    <span translate>rule.type.errors.required</span>
                </div>
            </div>


        </md-input-container>
```

Comment: i added those <div ng-messages="form.type.$error" ng-show="form.$submitted || form.type.$touched ||  form.type.$dirty ">
                <div ng-message-exp="['required']" ng-hide="form.type.$valid">